# unzip all files of folder (with error handling)

Tags: linux, unzip, gunzip

I am trying to unzip all gz files in a certain folder.
Now, I do this with a command "gunzip *.gz" in the folder. (very simple way!)

However, when an error occurs (such as, unexpected end of file), then the job is killed. I wanna just ignore such files with some problems, then continue to the next file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple script can skip the invalid files for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.gz ; do
  gunzip "$f" &> /dev/null || echo "Skipping file $f"
done
```